# Using Select * in a SQL JOIN returns the wrong id value for the wrong table

Tags: sql, join, select

I have two tables (PlayerDTO and ClubDTO) and am using a JOIN to fetch data as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM PlayerDTO AS pl
INNER JOIN ClubDTO AS cl
ON pl.currentClub = cl.id
WHERE cl.nation = 7
```

This returns the correct rows from PlayerDTO, but in every row the **id** column has been changed to the value of the **currentClub** column (eg instead of `pl.id 3,456 | pl.currentClub 97`, it has become `pl.id 97 | pl.currentClub 97`).

So I tried the query listing all the columns by name instead of `Select *`:

```
SELECT pl.id, pl.nationality, pl.currentClub, pl.status, pl.lastName FROM PlayerDTO AS pl
INNER JOIN ClubDTO AS cl
ON pl.currentClub = cl.id
WHERE cl.nation = 7
```

This works correctly and doesn’t change any values.

PlayerDTO has over 100 columns (I didn’t list them all above for brevity, but I included them all in the query) but obviously I don’t want to write every column name in every query.

So could somebody please explain why `Select *` changes the **id** value and what I need to do to make it work correctly? All my tables have a column called **id**, is that something to do with it?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: What is your justification, per an authoritative definition of join, that "every row the id column has been changed", and what does that mean exactly? (Otherwise you are just asking for yet another definition without us knowing what you already misunderstand.) [mre] [ask] [Help] Tables have no row order, although query results are ordered in a way that is consistent with an ORDER BY when they have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SELECT *...` is, according to the docs...

> shorthand for “select all columns.” (Source: [Dev.MySQL.com](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-tutorial-excerpt/8.0/en/selecting-all.html)

Both your tables have `id` columns, so which should be returned?  It's not indicated, so MySQL makes a guess.  So select what you want to select...

```
SELECT pl.id, *otherfieldsyouwant* FROM PlayerDTO AS pl...
```

Or...

```
SELECT pl.* FROM PlayerDTO AS pl...
```

Typically, `SELECT *` is bad form.  The odds you are using every field is astronomically low.  And the more data you pull, the slower it is.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the explanation. SELECT pl.* did indeed work. :-)

Comment: @Eatton & HoldOffHunger This does misleads & does not explain. SQL does not "guess". SQL tables have column order & it is defined on JOIN result per the inputs & \* uses it & here returns an id column for each table in the join, in the appropriate order. Also the only row order one can expect is per an ORDER BY but there isn't one. So the 1st id column is pl & if it seems to return cl that's just because of misinterpretation of what is being returned. There would be an ambiguity error for SELECT pl, but that's not the problem here.